# Asp.net allows users to see specific posts/content

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I am implementing something like Facebook posts, but I only want to limit it for users Alice and Bob to see, but John can't see it. May I know what is the proper way to implement this ? I tried googling but all I found is user based authorization, for IIS.

What I had in mind is to implement another table to add allow list, so if the allow list is empty I assume all users' friends are allow to see, but if there are users in the allowed list then only allowed users can see. However I think this might heavily increase the load of my db?

Comment: There are various approaches to authorisation. You seem to be looking at something like (possibly light weight) access control lists. But that's a potentially big topic with far too many options even if "might increase db load" wasn't already very non-specific. [SO] is about *specific* questions, this isn't.

Comment: Thanks @richard this is as specific as I can go. But considering Facebook to allow who sees what post on a wall, is that merely an ACL ? or some other smarter architecture ?